# Parameter in bash script with multiple type of separators

Tags: bash

I would like to use multiple types of separators as parameter in my bash script.

Example parameter types (space, comma, semicolon, mixed):

```
./x.sh par1 par2 par3
./x.sh par1,par2,par3
./x.sh par1;par2;par3;
./x.sh par1,par2;par3 par4
```

I have:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 for i in ${*//,/ }; do
    echo $i
 done
```

This works for space and comma, but not for semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in ${*//[,;]/ }; do
  echo $i
done
```

```sh
./x.sh "par1,par2;par3 par4"
par1
par2
par3
par4
```

`$*` is a [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters) that returns all arguments separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable (a space by default).

`${*//[,;]/ };` uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace all occurrences of [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) (characters `,` and `;`) by a space.

Comment: I tried this before, but I forgot to put parameters in quotes. Bingo!

Comment: @Adrian Btw, didn’t know this could be done in bash. Do you know what that regex loop feature is called? Would like to learn more about it.

Comment: It is called Parameter Expansion, although the `[ ,;]` is form glob which honestly i've just learn that It works like that, I mean inside the parameter expanion

Comment: It can also be written in a script like this: `for f; do printf '%s\n'  "${f//[,;]/ }"; done`  the `in` can be omitted. Or wrap it in a function if you like.

Comment: @Jetchisel Used your knowledge to enhance my answer. Love learning this tricks. Thanks again!